# count the number of words in a web page using javascript

Tags: javascript

Lets suppose i opened  a page http://vedabase.net/cc/adi/9/3/en. I am using firefox and have firebug installed in it. How can i find the number of word in this web page using  javascript running in the console of firebug.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
document.body.innerText.split(' ').length
```

for Firefox you can use (Firefox uses the [W3C-compliant](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent) [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) property.)

```
document.body.textContent.split(' ').length
```

Comment: i tried this but it shows "document.body.innerText is undefined"

Comment: firefox equivalent added

Comment: [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent): _Note that while textContent gets the content of all elements, including <script> and <style> elements, the mostly equivalent IE-specific property, innerText, does not_

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the blank spaces and newlines

```
document.body.innerText.split(/\s/).filter(function (txt) {return /\S/.test(txt)}).length;
```

You can see the words using

```
document.body.innerText.split(/\s/).filter(function (txt) {return /\S/.test(txt)});
```

On firefox, instead of `document.body.innerText` use `document.body.textContent`

Comment: [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent): _Note that while textContent gets the content of all elements, including <script> and <style> elements, the mostly equivalent IE-specific property, innerText, does not_

Comment: having tried on the link i gave. I opened the page "http://vedabase.net/cc/adi/9/3/en" and opened the firebug console and ran the command "document.body.innerText.split(/\s/).filter(function (txt) {return /\S/.test(txt)}).length;" it says  TypeError: document.body.innerText is undefined