# Count words with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, count, words

I am new to coding, so I would like to know how I can count words of an website with javascript. Should I use `.innerText` and a `for` loop?

Comment: `.innerText.split(" ").length` maybe?

Comment: First, [how do you define a word](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8niIHChc1Y) or at least, how do you delimit them—will em-dashes cause trouble? What about Japanese letters?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zUuzd/

Comment: Here is a previous question with the same subject:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498258/count-the-number-of-words-in-a-web-page-using-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Split on regular expression `/\W+/` (`\W` matches anything that is not a latin letter or arabic number or an underscore) :

```js
var text = "These are two sentences. They have ten words in total.";

alert(text.split(/\W+/).length)
```

More details on regexp can by found on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: `\W+` would be better.

Comment: @Xufox Any case where not having the `+` would give wrong result ?

Comment: `"These are two sentences. They have ten words in total.".split(/\W/).length` would give 12 because the empty strings after `.` are counted as well.

Comment: Other than that, this is the best solution so far as this even allows em-dashes etc. to delimit words. But what about normal dashes? For example, is `camel-case` two words or one?

Comment: Also, the description is wrong (_“`\W` match words”_). It should be “`\W` matches anything that is _not_ a latin letter or arabic number or an underscore”.

Answer (score 1):

May be it can help you:

```
<script>
var words = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.replace(/<.*?>/g, '');
console.log(words.match(/\S+/g).length);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would count the number of words as you type:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#count").on("keyup", function(){
        $("#num").html($("#count").html().split(" ").length-1);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle code here](https://jsfiddle.net/7sr1w3j9/)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you if the language on the site uses spaces to separate words.

```
$.fn.showWordCount = function (){
  "use strict";
  var $targ = $(this);
  var words = $targ.html().split(' ');
  var wordCount = words.length;
  alert(wordCount);
};

$('body *').showWordCount();
```

Proof it works: http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/rVJPOx